# Parsing transaction hash from rawblock data

Tags: transactions, blockchain, blockchain.info, hash, python

I got block raw data next url
https://blockchain.info/rawblock/00000000000000000002447735c7723ee9188322c0938e6587866a4458b9135f?format=hex

Can I find transaction hash in url used python?

Comment: The transaction in bitcoin contains only the hash of the previous transaction, so all **unspended** transaction doesn't have the hash inside the blockchain but you can calculate the hash of the transaction with the data and the Bitcoin rules. You found the example in your [previous post](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/96593/can-i-convert-hex-format-data-to-json)

Comment: the question is not clear!  Well you have given the URL for the whole block.  What is your question? you want to find the tx hash? in URL (that is decided by the webserver) ? in Python? (do you mean code or API call etc)?